# Passing a path as parameter to function

Tags: database, postgresql, plpgsql

I have a function in which I pass a `path` to a file as a parameter. Within the function, I want to `COPY` the data that is located at the `path`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION load(path varchar)
    RETURNS void
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
  AS
$$
BEGIN
    COPY foo FROM path
    WITH DELIMITER ';' 
    CSV HEADER;

    ...

end;
$$
```

This gives a `Syntax Error`, pointing to `path`. If I hardcode the `path` to `C:\Users....`, it works.
Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`copy` does not work with variables. Shape and execute dynamic SQL. Here is an illustration - your example modified. I am using [dollar quoting](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS) for clarity.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION load(path text) RETURNS void LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$
begin
 execute replace(
 $dynsql$
    COPY foo FROM '__PATH__'
    WITH DELIMITER ';' 
    CSV HEADER;
 $dynsql$,
 '__PATH__', path);

    ...

end;
$$
```